# Add method to string class in node.js express.js coffeescript

Tags: coffeescript

I want to add some my methods to generic types like string, int etc. in express.js (coffeescript). I am completely new in node. I want to do just this:

```
"Hi all !".permalink().myMethod(some).myMethod2();
5.doSomething();
variable.doSomethingElse();
```

How to do this ?

Comment: Meryn gives the right answer but changing basic types prototypes such as String is generally deprecated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add a method to the String prototype with:

```
String::permaLink = ->
   "http://somebaseurl/archive/#{@}"
```

`String::permalink` is shorthand for `String.prototype.permaLink`

You can then do:

```
somePermalink = "some-post".permaLink()
console.log somePermalink.toUpperCase()
```

This will call the the "String.prototype.permaLink" function with "this" set to the "some-post" string. The permaLink function then creates a new string, with the string value of "this" (`@` in Coffeescript) included at the end. Coffeescript automatically returns the value of the last expression in a function, so the return value of permaLink is the newly created string.

You can then execute any other methods on the string, including others you have defined yourself using the technique above. In this example I call toUpperCase, a built-in String method.

Comment: Thank you very much. But where can I put this code in my app ? (express.js)

Comment: You could put the code that extends the String prototype right in your main server.coffee or app.coffee file. Alternatively, you could put it in a separate file (say prototype_extensions.coffee) inside the same dir as your app.coffee and put `require 'prototype_extensions'` inside your app.coffee file. Because String is a global variable, any changes you make to String.prototype will be reflected throughout your app. But do read an Express tutorial!

Comment: I made a typo in the comment above: `require 'prototype_extensions'` should be `require './prototype_extensions'`, otherwise node will look for the module in the node_modules directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can use prototype to extend String or int object with new functions

```
String.prototype.myfunc= function () {
  return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
};
var mystring = "       hello, world        ";
mystring.myfunc();

'hello, world'
```

Comment: Op is asking for `coffeescript`